# チャットの部屋一覧でcreate new roomしようとすると、英語版SOに紐付いた部屋になる

Tags: サポート, 延期, チャット

[image: Related Site]

more sites... を選んで「スタック・オーバーフロー」で検索しても、出てきません。

これはバグでしょうか。

サイト公開までは新規に部屋は作れない、という仕様であれば、それはそれでとくに問題ないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

日本語で調べると出ません。それはバグかもしれないが、チャット全体が英語の為、優先が低いと思います。

とりあえず、スタック・オーバーフローで新しいルームを作成したい場合、「ja」を入力してください：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「サイトの部屋一覧でcreate new roomすると、そのサイトではなくStack OverflowがRelated Siteに設定されている」というのは日本語版SOに限った動作ではないんですね。「サイトの部屋一覧でcreate new roomすると、Related Siteにそのサイトが初めから設定されている」方が使いやすいと思います